# Postgres Connection Intermittently Hangs

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to connect to a database. Unfortunately, at times calling conn.execute stalls to the point where I can't even break out of a terminal with an interrupt (e.g. Ctrl+C). I don't see anything interesting in the Postgres logs, and I'm at a complete loss as to how to even begin debugging this. This occurs with any query.

I see this in both Python and applications like Dbeaver. One second it works, the other it hangs in an unrecoverable way.

Relevant code is quite simple:

```
import psycopg2
conn_string = "...."
query = "...."
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
```

This is on AWS RDS with Postgres v13.1. The application connecting to Postgres does not matter. It could be a Python script, a Ruby script, an app, PgAdmin.

Everything just hangs at the connection initial connection attempt. The resolution is to kill the process and try again until after umpteen times it works.

Comment: A lot more information needed. **Add as text update to question**: 1) Postgres version? Also is it community version or fork?  2) `psycopg2` version? 3) Where are the clients and database server relative to each other, same machine, same network, different networks? 4) What does the Postgres log show for the connection?

Comment: Would you accurately know if the things you do see in the log are interesting?  When ctrl-C does work, what do you see in the logs then?  Can you open a new putty or ssh or cygwin or xterm or whatever, or is the entire system frozen?  How does it eventually resolve?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. The process is frozen, the logs don't even show Ctrl+C being received. The resolution is to kill the parent process and try again until after umpteen times it works.